# Converting UIImage into PDF File

Tags: iphone

Iam trying to saving an UIImage in PDF file.
How can i do this? How i would save and image into pdf file and then export that pdf file?
Please suggest the solution for the issue i faced.

Thank You.

Comment: Why? While it's possible, PDF is optimized for storing documents and vector graphics, and UIImage is a bitmap...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you'd create a [CGPDFContext](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html), draw your UIImage into it, and save it to a file. Haven't done that myself, though.

Answer (score 15):

Hello there I've found that this works,
hope it helps!

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
    {
        // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
        NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

        // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
        [aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        // remove PDF rendering context
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
        NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

        NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

        // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
        [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like a good concept, but draws a blank PDF file? What is needed on the "aView" drawRect?

Answer (score 0):

I got a blank pdf as well. Got it working now though. Try changing:

```
//[aView drawRect:aView.bounds]; // <- This

[aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; // <- To This
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start a pdf graphics context, and then draw an image into it, using:

```
[UIImage drawInRect: someRect];
```

You can either see the docs, they give a good explanation of generating a pdf. There is a good tutorial on pdf generation [here](http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/).