# Can You Download Something as PDF from an iphone App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4

Is it possible to download a particular screen in an iphone application as a PDF? I have checked the iphone Developer portal and a lot of other places but couldnt find the answer. All i want to do is click on a button and that should download that screen as a pdf and store it in some place. Is this possible? If so where would you store it?

Comment: Are you talking about taking a screenshot on the phone itself in an app, or are you talking about doing it from Xcode while debugging? (thought I'd ask since it's tagged xcode)

Comment: Well i want the app to be able to do this. I would also want to test it on the debugger however the functionality has to be on the app on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

If you split your question in two questions - the answer is simple.

Q1) how can i take a screenshot programatically (into UIImage)?

A1) [How to take a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)

Q2) how can i convert a UIImage to PDF file?

A2) [Converting UIImage into PDF File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445335/converting-uiimage-into-pdf-file)