# Saving a view and its contents as image or pdf

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimage, pdf-generation

I have a view that has many textfields and values inserted into them. Now I want to save this view as an image or as a pdf.

Is there any way I can achieve this? I am using IOS 5.1 for the project

Comment: Many duplicate questions here... one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495370/image-from-uiview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting UIImage into PDF File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445335/converting-uiimage-into-pdf-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take screenshot of the view and save it:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[self.view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now you have a UIImage of the whole view content, you can use it the way you like..